# Create expandable bulleted list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating a file that will allow me to keep track of the costs of buying a house.
What I would like is a bulleted list that can be expandable.

For example, I have a "Furniture" category that includes 3 items (kitchen, wardrobe and bed), each with its own price. The Furniture entry contains the sum of the individual prices.

I would like to be able to expand and hide the secondary voices using a button similar to (+) and (-) next to the item Furniture.

How can I do that?

This is what I've done (on the left the expanded list, on the right the "hidden" list):

[image: what I've done]

What I would like is something similar to this (but with the addition of prices):

[image: What I want]

Comment: It's called outline in Excel: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff

Comment: @MátéJuhász. That's the answer. Post it please